# how to create a webpage with simple controls and python back end

Tags: python, web

i have a python function which takes text and some parameters as an input.
i want to build a simple web page with some controls:

1. a file upload control
2. a text box
3. some radio buttons to choose parameters
4. a submit button

user will either use the upload control or enter some text in the box.
upon submission my python function will run in the back end and return results to be displayed on the page.

as a complete web newbie i am wondering what would be the easiest way to approach this.

i am not sure on what machine this will run and what permissions i will have, so lets assume a generic LAMP server (if this makes any sense)

Comment: See [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org).

Comment: bottle too. http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/

Comment: web.py might be the simplest to do this.

Comment: ok. i found my answer. since the question was closed i will briefly describe it here. you first create an html page. html5 allows all the wanted controls. you wrap the controls with an html form tag. the form has a submit control upon which it invokes some action (given by the action attribute of the form). this action is your python script. now you modify your python code to work with cgi (see e.g. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm). cgi is a library which has access to the input fields of the html form. output from your python script will go back to the browser.

Comment: just to be clear: this means no need for flask, bottlepy or web.py

Answer (score 1):

To help myself get started quickly with flask/backbone.js web projects, I have created a "Hello World" web scaffold/skeleton to get myself started more quickly. It exists also to jog my memory on how the  basic features of flask/jinja/backbone.js work. You can clone it from [github](https://github.com/softwaredoug/flask_scaffold) to get started.